# Accounts with activities report

Tags: custom-reports

The requirement is to create a account report with activities and if the account has 5 comments so far, i need to generate the report with latest comment. i tried to filter it with date field again but date field shows only current date,yesterday or last week record. i want the report with latest comment if the comments were created one or two months before.

could some one please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the relative filter? Relative date filters let you filter on date fields using easy-to-understand, human-speech-inspired syntax.

For example, instead of filtering on Close Date greater than Jan 1, 2017, filter using a relative date: Close Date equals this year.

**LAST MONTH**  Starts at 12:00:00 AM on the first day of the month before the current month and continues for all the days of that month.

**THIS MONTH**  Starts at 12:00:00 AM on the first day of the current month and continues for all the days of that month.

**NEXT n MONTHS**   Starts at 12:00:00 AM on the first day of the month after the current month and continues until the end of the nth month.

**LAST n MONTHS**   Starts at 12:00:00 AM on the first day of the month that started n months before the current month and continues up to 11:59 PM on the last day of the month before the current month.

**n MONTHS AGO**    Starts at 12:00:00 AM on the first day of the month that started n months before the start of the current month and continues for all the days of that month.

**NEXT MONTH**  Starts at 12:00:00 AM on the first day of the month after the current month and continues for all the days of that month.

Read more here:- [Relative Date Filter Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=filter_dates_relative.htm&type=5)

Comment: Yes, i tried even if filter for last month, i am getting accounts with all comments.